# Farbtastic with php

Tags: php

Hey guys am developing an image creation app in which use a user is allowded to select a color range from Farbtastic color picker and the image is generated with a text.The text will be displayed in the color in which the user has selected from Farbtastic.

## html code(color picker)

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="farbtastic.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="farbtastic.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {


 $('#demo').hide();


   $('#picker').farbtastic('#color');
  });

 </script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="demo" style="color: red; font-size: 1.4em"></div>

<form action="" style="width: 400px;">
  <div class="form-item"><label for="color">Color:</label><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></div><div id="picker"></div>

</form>

<br>

<form action="image.php">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## My php code(image generation)

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

imagepng($im);

imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Am really stuck i have no idea how to integrate my html to php in doing this .what i need is to generate a colour on the text on image.The color must be from Farbtastic color picker in which the user has selected ..Any idea on how to do this or any code sample would be appreciated ..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html script, you should indicate the endpoint of php file, in first form markup, second form markup is unnecessary:

```
<form action="image.php" method="POST" style="width: 400px;">
<div class="form-item"><label for="color">Color:</label><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></div><div id="picker"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your php script, you should read color from POST array and then convert it to a rgb. Example below:

```
<?php
//read hex color and remove leading #
$hex_color = str_replace('#', '', $_POST['color']);
//convert hex color to rgb
$red = hexdec(substr($hex_color,0,2));
$green = hexdec(substr($hex_color,2,2));
$blue = hexdec(substr($hex_color,4,2));

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');

//use rgb color
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $red, $green, $blue);

imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

imagepng($im);

imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Comment: the code has no errors but the image didnt formed ..instead of images its showing a square .its not loading ..

Comment: why did you  add those hashtags ??..with str_replace ...i didnt get it ..:) it will be really helpful if you tell me tht

Comment: because value="#123456" has hashtag;)

Comment: i removed those hashtags ...but it also needed hastag

Comment: i suppose that farbtastic put value with hashtag into input